# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException - Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception

Here is my code:

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;

public class Sender
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // get the initial context
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

        // lookup the queue object
        Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("queue/queue0");

        // lookup the queue connection factory
        QueueConnectionFactory connFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.
           lookup("queue/connectionFactory");

        // create a queue connection
        QueueConnection queueConn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();

        // create a queue session
        QueueSession queueSession = queueConn.createQueueSession(false,Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // create a queue sender
        QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
        queueSender.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

        // create a simple message to say "Hello"
        TextMessage message = queueSession.createTextMessage("Hello");

        // send the message
        queueSender.send(message);

        // print what we did
        System.out.println("sent: " + message.getText());

        // close the queue connection
        queueConn.close();
    }
}
```

Eclipse is not reporting any errors in the above code -- I'm able to compile successfully. However, when I try running it, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify       
class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an  application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
  at Sender.main(Sender.java:21)
```

Can anyone please help me fix the bug? I tried fixing it for a few hours but still cannot figure it out.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ops/faq.html#1

Answer (score 23):

We need to specify the INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, PROVIDER_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD etc. of JNDI to create an `InitialContext`.

In a standalone application, you can specify that as below

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
    "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.wiz.com:389");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "joeuser");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "joepassword");

Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

But if you are running your code in a Java EE container, these values will be fetched by the container and used to create an `InitialContext` as below

```
System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL);
```

and

these values will be set while starting the container as JVM arguments.
So if you are running the code in a container, the following will work

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "running the code in a container" ?

Comment: As I understand container - it is tomcat, jboss, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If working on EJB client library:

You need to mention the argument for getting the initial context.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
```

If you do not, it will look in the project folder for properties file. Also you can include the properties credentials or values in your class file itself as follows:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
```

**URL_PKG_PREFIXES:** Constant that holds the name of the environment property for specifying the list of package prefixes to use when loading in URL context factories.

The EJB client library is the primary library to invoke remote EJB components.
This library can be used through the InitialContext. To invoke EJB components the library creates an EJB client context via a URL context factory. The only necessary configuration is to parse the value org.jboss.ejb.client.naming for the java.naming.factory.url.pkgs property to instantiate an InitialContext.