# Jms java se client and javax.naming.NoInitialContextException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms

I am newbie in JMS and this is my first attempt use it. I use glassfish4. I followed [this tutorial](http://techtipsjava.blogspot.ru/2013/05/jms-on-glassfish-queue-and-topic-with.html) I set glassfish resources and in EAR application added message driven bean. Plus I opened 7676 port in firewall. After that I created a SE project (different host,i.e. not the server jvm) with one class SeClient and with the following
    package seclient;

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class SeClient {

 public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {

  // Commands to create Topic
  // asadmin --port 4848 create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Topic TestTopic
  // asadmin --port 4848 create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory TestTopicConnectionFactory

  String msg = "Hello from remote JMS Client";

  SeClient test = new SeClient();

  System.out.println("==============================");
  System.out.println("Publishig message to Topic");
  System.out.println("==============================");
  System.out.println();
  test.sendMessage2Topic(msg);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("==============================");
  System.exit(0);
 }


 private void sendMessage2Topic(String msg) throws Exception{

  // Provide the details of remote JMS Client
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "mq://x.x.x.x:7676");//I use my server's IP

  // Create the initial context for remote JMS server
  InitialContext cntxt = new InitialContext(props);
  System.out.println("Context Created");

  // JNDI Lookup for TopicConnectionFactory in remote JMS Provider
  TopicConnectionFactory qFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory)cntxt.lookup("TestTopicConnectionFactory");

  // Create a Connection from TopicConnectionFactory
  Connection connection = qFactory.createConnection();
  System.out.println("Connection established with JMS Provide ");

  // Initialise the communication session
  Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

  // Create the message
  TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
  message.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
  message.setText(msg);

  // JNDI Lookup for the Topic in remote JMS Provider
  Topic topic = (Topic)cntxt.lookup("TestTopic");

  // Create the MessageProducer for this communication
  // Session on the Topic we have
  MessageProducer mp = session.createProducer(topic);

  // Broadcast the message to Topic
  mp.send(message);
  System.out.println("Message Sent: " + msg);

  // Make sure all the resources are released
  mp.close();
  session.close();
  cntxt.close();
 }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException:
>   Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an
>   applet parameter, or in an application resource file: 
>   java.naming.factory.initial   at
>   javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
>     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
>     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)  at
>   seclient.SeClient.sendMessage2Topic(SeClient.java:64)     at
>   seclient.SeClient.main(SeClient.java:45) Java Result: 1

Please, say what is wrong with my code/actions.

**EDIT:** I changed password in gf - configuration - server config - JMS hosts - default_JMS_host and added to the code

```
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "xxxxxx");
```

But same result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javax.naming.NoInitialContextException - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779510/javax-naming-noinitialcontextexception-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the value for the variable CLASSPATH: From your Glassfish lib folder and From your Glassfish modules folder ;c:\Glassfish\lib*;c:\Glassfish\modules*;