# How to get initial context from GlassFish server in Java SE?

Tags: java, glassfish, initial-context

I have a class like below:

```
public class Poligon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/javaee7/ConnectionFactory");
            Destination destination = (Destination) ctx.lookup("jms/javaee7/Topic");
            JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext();
            OrderDTO order = context.createConsumer(destination).receiveBody(OrderDTO.class);
            System.out.println("Order received: " + order);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Poligon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to get the InitialContext() form the server (glassfish) running on localhost, but I get the below error:

```
SEVERE: null
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or  system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  
    java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at poligon.Poligon.main(Poligon.java:29)
```

I know I have to create ldap realm on glassfish and add the below code (? - dont know the exact values) to my class:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "?");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "?");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "?");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "?");

Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

My problem is that I dont know what values should be at:

```
Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY
Context.PROVIDER_URL (I want it on localhost)
Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL
Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS
```

And I dont know how I should configure glassfish server?

[image]

maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.appclient.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Fix question for clarity

Comment: Could you tell me which part is unclear?

Comment: Is the question: "How do make availble resources located on glassfish server in my client application?"?

Comment: see if this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779510/javax-naming-noinitialcontextexception-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use JNDI you need to specify the `java.naming.factory.initial` somehow, just like the error message says.

There are multiple ways of doing this:

You could specify it as a system property in Glassfish, through `server (Admin server)` -> `Properties`

Alternatively, you could specify it in a HashTable and pass it to the constructor of `InitialContext`:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  
    "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");

Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

If you use Spring you could also do this:

```
<bean id="myJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">com.sun.enterprise.naming</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.state">com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/context.html for more information.

As far as the actual values go, the Spring config above is what we actually use with `Glassfish`. We do not specify provider url or credentials..

I don't think this is really connected to creating an ldap-realm, Glassfish might use JNDI to lookup the realm though.

Edit:

I think I might understand what the problem is, you are trying to access remote classes from a client. With this assumption, you can use Spring to do this, with JndiTemplate. Assuming that the server makes available the correct EJB-classes, do this on the client side:

Create a bean for JndiTemplate:

```
  <bean id="myJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
      <props>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory</prop>
        <prop key="org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost">${servername}</prop>
        <prop key="org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort">${jndiport}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

You can then use this bean to lookup stuff on the server. If you want to take it a step further, and call your own remote EJB-classes, you could also do this:

```
  <bean id="ejbProxy"
        class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean"
        abstract="true">
    <property name="refreshHomeOnConnectFailure" value="true"/>
    <property name="cacheHome" value="true"/>
    <property name="lookupHomeOnStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="false"/>
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="mySpringTemplate"/>
  </bean>
```

And then define beans as:

```
  <bean id="someRemoteService" parent="ejbProxy">
    <property name="jndiName"
              value="com.company.service.MyRemoteService"/>
    <property name="businessInterface"
              value="com.company.service.MyRemoteService"/>
  </bean>
```

You can inject this like a regular bean, any calls to it will be made to the server.

Comment: I used the hashTable solution but i got an error:
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory]

Comment: Hmm that class should be included with Glassfish. You are running this on glassfish?

Comment: No it is stand alone application.

Comment: Then you need to add some jars to the classpath, glassfish-embedded-all has the class, with a pom dependency to org.glassfish.main.appclient.client:gf-client (has a transitive dep to glassfish-naming which holds the class) should also do the trick. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002948/how-to-setup-jndi-for-glassfish-3-1-2-for-a-stand-alone-client

Comment: i updated my maven repository and now it says:
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:JMS:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.4.v201112200901, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.3.2, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:jar:2.3.2, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen:jar:2.3...

Comment: Something to do with your remote maven repositories i guess. Make sure you have the correct remote repositories set up.

Comment: In your `main()` method you are instantiating an `InitialContext` and calling various Glassfish methods without ever starting Glassfish. See https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/embedded-server-guide.pdf for information on how to configure your project and start Glassfish.

Comment: I don't think an embedded glassfish it what op wants, but the question is not very clear so can't be sure..

Answer (score 1):

In order to access glassfish (and too look up the EIB) running on localhost I had to use:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

        java.util.Hashtable<String, String> hashTable = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        hashTable.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
        hashTable.put(Context.STATE_FACTORIES, "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
        hashTable.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(hashTable);

    // Looks up the EJB with JNDI
        BookEJBRemote bookEJB = (BookEJBRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/chapter08-service-1.0/BookEJB!org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter08.BookEJBRemote");
    }
}
```

When glassfish is running on localhost, Context can be initiated with default properties (without hashtable parameter)

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
```