# Properties MySQL context

Tags: mysql, properties, ejb

I am studying the tutorial javarevoltions JSF 2 + PrimeFaces 5 + 4 + Spring Hibernate 4.

Essse tutorial is based on weblogic server and Oracle database.

My problem is I want to use glassfish with MySQL instead.

There is a file called utilidades.java containing webologic properties.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class Utilities {
    public static Object getEJBRemote (nameEJB String, String iface) throws Exception {
    Context context;

    Properties props = new Properties ();
    props.put (Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    props.put (Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http: // localhost: 7001");
    try {
        context = new InitialContext (props);
        String lookup nameEJB + = "#" + iface;
        System.out.println ("Lookup" + lookup);
        return context.lookup (lookup);
    } Catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception ("There is EJB: '" + nameEJB + "'.");
    }
    }
}
```

I've changed to:

```
props.put (Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean");
props.put (Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http: // localhost: 4848");
```

This I saw a tutorial on the Internet, using glassfish and mysql. I created the ping successfully datasource in glassfish.

When I do a debbug it appears:

> ex = (javax.naming.NoInitialContextException)
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Can not instantiate class:
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean [Root exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean can not be cast to
>   javax.naming .spi.InitialContextFactory]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory` is not an `InitialContextFactory`.  I think the value you want for Glassfish is `com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory`:

```
 Properties props = new Properties ();
    props.put (Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    props.put (Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http: // localhost: 7001");
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843514/how-to-get-initial-context-from-glassfish-server-in-java-se) has more detail.